# Keycloak Grails Spring - redirection after login

Tags: spring, grails, keycloak

I have a spring GRAILS application using Keycloak 4.5.

For some reason the redirection after login proceeds to http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml/saml/SSO/alias/localhost

instead of http://localhost:8080/springapp/ - the URL it should be going.

This might be a Spring Security suite redirection issue.

But the 'Valid Redirect URIs' box requires a * wildcard character, if I put any other URI it does not work.

For example, a URL - like http://localhost:8080/springapp/
 - it complains, and fails to proceed to the login screen, and shows a message "Invalid redirect uri".

Any idea what needs to be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Its a post login action which is failing, it seems Keycloak is logging in correctly, but the 'http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml/saml/SSO/alias/localhost' URI is not getting picked up/resolved by Spring Security.